# Building AWS secure tunneling localproxy on rPi

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile the AWS iot localproxy on an rPi (have tried 3 and 4 and getting the same issue). I follow the instructions here >> https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-securetunneling-localproxy

I have been sucessful compiling on macOS and the binary works, but when building on an rPi I get the folowing error...

```
    [  4%] Linking CXX executable bin/localproxytest
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprotobuf-lite.a(arena.cc.o): in function `google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::Init(bool)':
arena.cc:(.text+0xa60): undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/localproxytest.dir/build.make:292: bin/localproxytest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:97: CMakeFiles/localproxytest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

It seems to be a problem linking to '__atomic_fetch_add_8' or the atomic libs?  Any clues on how to resolve?  Anyone been successful building this on an rPi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an issue with CMake and the order of linking with ld.

In CMakeLists.txt
Moving `atomic` to be the last link command after all the sources fixed this for me

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-securetunneling-localproxy/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L94

`if(NOT APPLE AND NOT MSVC) target_link_libraries(${AWS_TUNNEL_LOCAL_PROXY_TARGET_NAME} atomic) target_link_libraries(${AWS_TUNNEL_LOCAL_PROXY_TEST_NAME} atomic) endif()`

should be below
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-securetunneling-localproxy/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L111

`target_link_libraries(${AWS_TUNNEL_LOCAL_PROXY_TEST_NAME} ${Protobuf_LITE_STATIC_LIBRARY})`

Comment: you are a legend!!! That fixed it and I was able to build the binary.